# View model event bind to button click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-binding

My Viewmodel has an event

```
public class TestViewModel 
{
    public event RoutedEventHandler Run;
}
```

I wanna trigger this event when user clicked on a button in view

How to bind this with a button in a view ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) are meant for controls not view models, if you have something that should be executed upon a button click a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) would be more suitable in my opinion, it can easily be bound to the [`Button.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use DelegateCommand for such behavior.

In your View Model:

```
private DelegateCommand _runCommand;
public DelegateCommand RunCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_runCommand == null)
            _runCommand = new DelegateCommand(Run, CanRun);

        return _runCommand;
    }
}

void Run()
{
    ... 
}

bool CanSaveAction()
{
    return true;
}
```

On your page:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RunCommand}" />
```